What is the meaning of individual Resource Manager like Heap, Btree, XLOG etc from WAL file?
In PostgreSQL v15 I have installed pg_walinspect extension. I am trying to understand what is individual resource manager fields.
Like I understand resource manager tells us where individual data change has happened. I did several actions like INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, CHECKPOINT and got result (I have heavily clean the output, just to display one resource manager type per row):
 start_lsn  |   end_lsn   |  xid   | resource_manager | record_type       |
------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------------+
15/61E54B08 | 15/61E54B48 | 337813 | Heap             | INSERT            |
15/61E54B48 | 15/61E54C10 | 337813 | Btree            | INSERT_LEAF       |
15/61E577A8 | 15/61E57820 |      0 | XLOG             | CHECKPOINT_ONLINE |
15/61E61C78 | 15/61E61CA8 | 337848 | Standby          | LOCK              |
15/61E61CA8 | 15/61E61CD8 | 337848 | Storage          | CREATE            |
15/61E75758 | 15/61E75A98 | 337848 | Heap2            | MULTI_INSERT      |
15/61E83610 | 15/61E838B8 | 337848 | Transaction      | COMMIT            |

Now look at resource_manager attribute. What is the meaning of:

Heap - Is this memory or disk? It looks to me it is memory.
Btree - I assume index related (b-tree index).
XLOG - I assume WAL log related (I executed CHECKPOINT command).
Standby - No idea on this one.
Storage - I assume related to disk storage.
Heap2 - Probably similar to Heap, but what?
Transaction - Happens on commit/rollback.


They are just labels.  They have no inherent meaning. Knowing what the label are makes it easier to find the relevant part of the source code.

"Heap" and "Heap2" are for changes to a table. (Access exclusive) locks have to be logged only for the benefit of a standby server.
